# sizeWithAttributes results in "NSString is not identical to NSObject"

Tags: ios, swift

My code was running ok on iOS 8.0 and since I updated to Xcode 6.1/SDK 8.1, I cannot get my swift code compiling

I am trying to get the CGSize from a NSString like so

```
let part1="my text"
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
var dict = [NSFontAttributeName:font]
let size: CGSize = part1.sizeWithAttributes(dict)
```

On the last line I got the error "NSString is not identical to NSObject"

Can somebody help?

Actually I found the solution, here is the lines to add to make it work.

```
let part1="my text"
let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
if let fontNotNil=font {
    var dict = [NSFontAttributeName:fontNotNil]
    let size: CGSize = part1.sizeWithAttributes(dict)
}
```

Comment: How is `part1` declared?

Comment: better unwrap font `var dict = [NSFontAttributeName:font!]`

Comment: @codester Explicit unwrapping should not be done unless there is no chance, under any circumstances, that is can be nil. In this case the API specifies it as an Optional. it should be unwrapped in an `if let ...` statement.

Comment: Statements 2 and 3 of the OP's answer can be combined into one line: `if let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30) {`.

Comment: unwrapping font worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let part1: NSString = "my text"
```

Comment: Nope, it did not help. Same error remains

Answer (score 0):

The Optionals all need proper unwrapping"

```
let part1: NSString! = "my text"  // For the test since we do not know the type of part1

if let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30) {
    let dict = [NSFontAttributeName:font] as NSDictionary
    let size: CGSize = part1.sizeWithAttributes(dict)
    println("size: \(size)")
}
```

Output:

> size: (96.6796875,33.515625)